# XPATH find a node if no other node has a sertin value

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, dtd

i need to return all of the book only if ther is no book with the price of 14.95....

the DTD

```
<!ELEMENT inventory (book)+>
<!ELEMENT book (title, author+, publisher+, price, chapter*)>
<!ATTLIST book num ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT chapter (title, (paragraph* | section*))>
<!ELEMENT section (title?, paragraph*)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT publisher (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT price (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST price currency CDATA #FIXED "usd">
<!ELEMENT paragraph (#PCDATA | emph | image)*>
<!ELEMENT emph (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image EMPTY >
<!ATTLIST image
          file
          CDATA #REQUIRED
          height CDATA #IMPLIED
          width CDATA #IMPLIED >
```

xml for example the xml is not constraint to be this one

```
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inventory SYSTEM "books.dtd">
   <inventory>
      <book num="b1">
         <title>Snow Crash</title>
         <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
         <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
         <price>14.95</price>
         <chapter>
         <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
         <paragraph>
            This is the
            <emph>first</emph>
            paragraph.
            <image file="firstParaImage.gif"/>
            After image...
         </paragraph>
         <paragraph>
            This is the
            <emph>second</emph>
            paragraph.
            <image file="secondParaImage.gif"/>
            After image...
         </paragraph>
      </section>
   </chapter>
</book>
<book num="b3">
   <title>Zodiac</title>
   <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
   <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
   <price>7.50</price>
   <chapter>
      <title>Zodiac - Chapter A</title>
   </chapter>
</book>
</inventory>
```

i konw how to find all of the book with price difrent from 14.95.. but i dont now how to do the if statment in XPTH
the assigment is in XPTH only

Comment: Please make sure to post **valid** XML, especially when also posting DTDs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns all books when there is none with price = 14.96:

```
(//book)[not(//book[price = 14.95])]
```

This returns all books with price = 14.95 or all if there is none:

```
//book[price = 14.95 or not(//book[price = 14.95])]
```

If your XPath engine is optimizing badly, this could be faster:

```
(//book)[not(//book[price = 14.95])] | //book[price = 14.95]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the most simple way in my opinion:

```
/*[not(book/price='14.95')]/book
```